# Override IE web certificate error using excel macro

Tags: html, excel, vba

How to over ride the certificate error message and click the link **"Continue to this website (not recommended)."** with a excel macro.

[image]

Please find the code I have created,

```
Sub Cert_error()

Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String

On Error GoTo Err_Clear
MyURL = "https://cacert.org/"    'or you can use "https://www.pcwebshop.co.uk/"
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True
For Each MyHTML_Element In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("img")
If MyHTML_Element.ID = "overridelink" Then MyHTML_Element.Click: Exit For
    Next
Err_Clear:
  If Err <> 0 Then
  Err.Clear
Resume Next
  End If

End Sub
```

and please find the HTML tag below

```
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="left" id="continueToSiteAlign" aria-labelledby="continueToSite" valign="middle">
        <h4 id="continueToSite">
            <img class="actionIcon" id="ImgOverride" alt="Not recommended icon" src="red_shield.png" border="0"><a name="overridelink" id="overridelink" href="https://cacert.org/">Continue to this website (not recommended).</a>
        </h4>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Kindly let me know if we can click that link and proceed to the website using excel macro.

Thanks in advance.